# How to get all pictures within a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a variable number of pictures (icons) in each cell (from 1 to 5), each picture with its own hyperlink. For each cell I need to identify how many pictures there are in it, and then fill in next to the cell, the HyperLink names/addresses.

The most important part I need to solve is how to identify and access all the pictures in any given cell. Getting the hyperlink address should be easy then.

---

I could turn the problem on its head if it would make it easier to solve and loop through every picture and return its location - if that is possible.

Comment: Good luck in your endeavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will run this macro for activesheet where your shapes are located...

Assuming also that `TopLeft corner` of the shape is reference point of your shape cell location...

The following subroutine should provide you either complete solution or a good start for further adjustments.

```
Sub qSolution()

    Dim SHP As Shape
    Dim rowSHP As Long
    Dim colSHP As Long

    For Each SHP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        rowSHP = SHP.TopLeftCell.Row
        colSHP = SHP.TopLeftCell.Column

        If Cells(rowSHP, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) <= colSHP Then
            Cells(rowSHP, colSHP + 1) = SHP.Hyperlink.Address
        Else
            Cells(rowSHP, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = _
                                        SHP.Hyperlink.Address
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to find a solution which is very similar to this. This would have been a life saver if I had not - thanks so much for this!